# How can I read bytes from a file in iphone application, chunk by chunk?

Tags: iphone, file, streaming

I am trying to implement an iphone application which can read some fixed amount of bytes from a file and store in another file. this process will go on up to the end of the file. I am very new to iphone application so please help me on that . Is there any parent classes out there for this specific type of implementation?

Answer (score 7):

I had a very large file which couldn't be read with NSData methods, so I used the following (per TechZen's suggestion for fine grain control).

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
[fileHandle seekToFileOffset:offset];
NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:length];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to copy the file, use [NSFileManager's copy functions.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW26)

If you just want specific bytes in a file, you can load the file using [NSData's file methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW5) then you can get specific blocks of bytes and write them to file.

If you want more fine grain control, use [NSFileHandler](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/readDataToEndOfFile).

Edit01:

[This page](http://www.myths.com/pub/doc/oh_really/other/Programming_in_Objective-C/0672325861_ch16lev1sec3.html) has examples for close to what you want. I don't have anything on hand.

Comment: Hi

   Thanks for your quick response . and can please give me some sample code appilication for reading chunk by chunk and writing to the another file.

Thanks ,
KamalBhr.

Comment: @KamalBhr there are always several example programs with each class. Check `Xcode Organizer Documentation`.